# Reg: Angular API Return data with array index "value below was evaluated just now”

Tags: angular7

i am using Angular for front end. i am using the API request to bring languages and phrases. return data is pushed into declared array variable.

````
```public data = [];
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getMyLang();
}
async getMyLang() {
    const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'X-API-KEY': 'xxxxxx',
        })
    };
const param = new FormData();
param.append('language', 'en');
await this.http.post('api url', param, headers).subscribe((data1) => {
    this.data.push(data1);
});
````

}```
when i call this method it pushes the data. after console this variable into component am getting following results.
[console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hvzb.png)

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i am getting the values like this. here i need to get language and phrases
[link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hvzb.png)